# How to Open Notepadd ++ With Textbox.text?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, notepad++

I have a small program that I am working on that grabs a script within an object model. I can get the script to display in the text box and I can get notepad++ to launch on button click.

What I would love to do is have the text from the text box open inside notepad++ so that i may edit the script.

Does anyone out there have any ideas?

Comment: Save it to a temp file and then open it with System.Diagnostic.Process.Start("c:\Program Files\notepad++\notepad++.exe", "C:\Temp\tempFileName.doc")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save the text from your text box to a file, like this:

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("path and name of text file.txt", textBox1.Text)
```

Now you can force the user to use Notepad, by doing this:

```
Process.Start("path to notepad.exe", "path and name of text file.txt")
```

Or you can have the system determine what the user's preferred application (say they have Notepad++) is for a `.txt` by doing this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("path and name of text file.txt")
```

Comment: glad this answer helped, feel free to up-vote the answer as well. :-)